# Unable to run docker for my Windows Server 2016 in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, virtual-machine

This is my VM in Azure.

OS: Windows Server 2016 DataCenter
Size: Standard D4s v3

Error that I see now:[image: [Error screenshot]]

I see that virtualization is enabled from task manager.

Any folks know how to fix this issue and could help me please?  :)

I try to use this platform to run the docker service from my windows server.
Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the results successfully like below:***

Created a virtual machine with windows server 2016 like below:

[image]

In the Remote desktop open powershell ISE -> Run as administrator use the below cmd:

```pascal
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 
set-executionpolicy unrestricted 
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```

[image]

```pascal
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Force

Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
Restart-Computer -Forc
```

[image]

[image]

Once you restart your system to enable the Docker features run the following command to see the Docker information like below:

```js
docker version
```

[image]

```
Client: Mirantis Container Runtime
 Version:           20.10.9
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.12m2
 Git commit:        591094d
 Built:              21:34:30
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
Server: Mirantis Container Runtime
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.9
  API version:      1.41 
  Go version:       go1.16.12m2
  Git commit:       591094d
  Built:             21:34:30
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Now, you can run the container by the docker run command like below:

```js
Start-Service Docker
```

docker run –it hello-world powershell

[image]

If still, the error persists: As per github by *Tahseen* in your terminal try `docker login` then `docker run hello-world`

And check `Docker Desktop` application is running. If not, Try to install [docker desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/) on windows and run this command

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

***Reference***:

[How to Install and Run Docker on Windows Server 2016, 2019, 2022 by (cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk)](https://cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/how-to-install-and-run-docker-on-windows-server-2016-2019-2022/)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the steps. But when I go through that, I still couldn't manage to run the hello world stuff correctly in docker.


PS C:\windows\system32> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.

Also try to install docker desktop but no luck for that as it only supports Win10 OS.